# Page vibrates at the mouse wheel event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mousewheel

I need to fix an issue that will vibrate at the mouse wheel event.
It seems to be a jquery, script problem.
This is just a page that is made up of html, css and jQuery.
This is test server.

http://ivenet.co.kr/renewal/production.php

You can check it in the chrome developer tool and use the script in fulpage_10.js.

mousewheel I looked up and modified the DOMMouseScroll event. However, the mouse wheel page is still annoying.

Answer (score 0):

It seens that you try to treat the scroll behavior of the page but you still allow the browser to handle it.

So, the place that you treat the mouse wheel (in your event listener) also do an `event.preventDefault();` at the begining of the function.